# Does 'g_thread_join' delete 'gpointer data'?

Tags: gtk, glib

From the reference manual: "g_thread_join() consumes the reference to the passed-in thread . This will usually cause the GThread struct and associated resources to be freed."

Does 'g_thread_join' call delete on 'gpointer data' passed to 'g_thread_create/g_thread_new'? Or is the manual just talking about freeing the 4 or 8 bytes that the gpointer itself is occupying?

Answer (score 0):

This gives a clue:

> This will **usually** cause the GThread struct and associated resources to be freed.

From the manual ([`g_thread_join()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html#g-thread-join)):

> Use `g_thread_ref()` to obtain an extra reference if you want to keep the GThread alive beyond the `g_thread_join()` call.

This means that **the thread** is killed, unless (and that explains the "usually") you keep a reference to it before the call.